# What is the tranformation of quaternions written below in code?

Tags: c++, transformation, ros, quaternions, euler-angles

I have already ask this on code review, since this is a c++ code, which works, but they said it is better here. 
So I have some code which rotates a quaternion (orix, oriy, oriz, oriw) to another quaternion, but this rotation is written badly and someone could mabye do it in less lines.
So I have two questions does someone knows how this quaternion is rotated? I think it is rotated -pi/2 around y in euler angles?
And second does someone know how to write this better?

This is the full code, which does a transformation (with the imports tf2).

Edit: yes, tf2 is a library. here the link: [docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2/](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Quaternion.html)

```
            tf2::Quaternion quat(orix, -oriy, oriz, oriw);
            tf2::Quaternion q_rot;
            tf2::Vector3 rotation_vector(0.7071068, 0, 0.7071068);
            q_rot.setRotation(rotation_vector, M_PI);
            quat = q_rot*quat;
            quat.normalize();   
            tf2::Matrix3x3 matrix(quat);
            tf2::Matrix3x3 change_y(1,0, 0, 0, -1,0 ,0 ,0, 1);
            matrix = change_y * matrix;

            double roll, pitch, yaw;
            matrix.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
            quat.setRPY(roll,pitch,yaw);`
```

Comment: I would guess the `matrix` that you get is not actually a rotation matrix (but contains a reflection). Thus, I wouldn't expect `matrix.getRPY()` to do anything meaningful.

Comment: why are you changing Y axis to -Y?

Answer (score 1):

The `rotation_vector` is actually defining the axis of rotation, so you are rotating `M_PI` around this vector defined as `[0.7 0 0.7]`, which would be similar to rotate around y-axis by `M_PI/4` - thus generating a new coordinate frame with `[x' y' z']` - and then rotate `M_PI` around your current z'-axis.

Perhaps this ROS [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions) might help.

And this should be enough for you to rotate a quaternion given a desired roll, pitch and yaw rotation.

```
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>

tf2::Quaternion q_orig, q_rot, q_new;

// Get the original orientation of 'commanded_pose'
tf2::convert(commanded_pose.pose.orientation , q_orig);

double r=3.14159, p=0, y=0;  // Rotate the previous pose by 180* about X
q_rot.setRPY(r, p, y);

q_new = q_rot*q_orig;  // Calculate the new orientation
q_new.normalize();

// Stuff the new rotation back into the pose. This requires conversion into a msg type
tf2::convert(q_new, commanded_pose.pose.orientation);
```

Comment: thanks for this good answer. Do you also know what the first line does? -y? That rotates another pi/4 around y in euler angles?

Comment: You may need to use some methods from this header, because the orientation you received maybe from another type, them you have to convert it.  "ROS uses two quaternion datatypes: msg and 'tf.' To convert between them in C++, use the methods of tf2_geometry_msgs."

Comment: I didn't understand your other questions `-y?` and `That rotates another pi/4 around y in euler angles`. What did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The line below is encoding a reflection transformation on the XZ-plane of the rotation axis of "quat":

```
tf2::Quaternion quat(orix, -oriy, oriz, oriw);
```

Next they just define a rotation of pi/2 rad around an axis in the XZ-plane.

```
tf2::Vector3 rotation_vector(0.7071068, 0, 0.7071068);
q_rot.setRotation(rotation_vector, M_PI);
```

Next they do a composition of rotations (order matters):

```
quat = q_rot*quat;
quat.normalize();
```

Next they change the mathematical representation from quaternions to matrix algebra:

```
tf2::Matrix3x3 matrix(quat);
```

Next they define again a reflection transformation about the XZ-plane:

```
tf2::Matrix3x3 change_y(1,0, 0, 0, -1,0 ,0 ,0, 1);
```

Next line is compositing that reflection to the current transformation:

```
matrix = change_y * matrix;
```

Finally they are passing back from matrix to quaternions:

```
double roll, pitch, yaw;
matrix.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
quat.setRPY(roll,pitch,yaw);`
```

Since you can represent a reflection using pure quaternions (see https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/reflection/quaternion/index.htm) then I argue that the following expression is equivalent to the code above:

```
// pure quaternion for doing reflection
tf2::Quaternion j(0, 1, 0, 0); 
// j*X*j is the reflection of X on the plane with normal j
quat = j*q_rot*j*quat*j*j;
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
quat = -j*q_rot*j*quat;
```

It is hard to tell if those expressions are truly equivalent because of the change between matrix and quaternions, so a numerical test could be done for confirmation that I haven't messed things up with signs. I haven't tested this so take it as is.